# ERROR:-528 MEssage: [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Maximum output rowsize (32767) exceeded

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, informix

I face the following exception when i try to `get data` from table with the following structure:

> ERROR:-528 MEssage: [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Maximum output
>   rowsize (32767) exceeded.

---

```
CREATE TABLE dr66req
   (
   req_ser     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   req_desc    LVarChar(32739),


);
```

Comment: Show us the code which you are using to get data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ref:](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.em.doc/errors_ids115.html)

The total number of bytes that this statement selects exceeds the
maximum that can be passed between the database server and the program.

Try following-

1) Make sure that the columns selected are the ones that you intended.
2) Check that you have not named some very wide character column by
mistake, neglected to specify a substring, or specified too long a
substring. If the selection is what you require, rewrite this SELECT
statement into two or more statements, each of which selects only some
of the fields.
3) If it is a join of several tables, you might best select
all desired data INTO TEMP; then select individual columns of the
temporary table.
4)If this is a fetch via a cursor in a program, you
might revise the program as follows. 
First, change the cursor to select only the ROWID of the desired row.
Second, augment the FETCH statement with a series of SELECT statements, each of which selects one or a few columns WHERE ROWID = the saved row ID.